# php warning: access denied

Tags: php, apache, web

When I try to load a website from `/var/www/html/` it reports this error:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for      user 'root'@'localhost'
```

It says that the raw responsible for the issue is this

```
$link = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Make sure your username and password are correct

Answer (score 0):

Verify the permission tables on the server and that you're connecting to the correct server.

You must allow remote login on MySQL server to root user using the command below

**Allow from localhost**

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*root_user_password' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

**Allow from anywhere**

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*root_user_password' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

**Allow from some host**

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'X.X.X.X' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*root_user_password' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

> Above command must be followed by `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
>   restart on MySQL service

That combination of username, host, and password is not allowed to connect to the server.

Comment: You should never allow remote connections to MySQL. This is a major security issue.

Comment: if I show grants it reports: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION but it doesn't work